# What does this '${image##*/}' brace expansion do?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm unable to understand what is the use of the following expansion in this code snippet:

```
image=$1
image_id=${image##*/}
```

I tried doing `echo ${image##*/}` for multiple values of `image` but I got the same results every time. Can this piece of code be removed?

```
$ image='var3-image'
$ echo ${image##*/}
var3-image
$ image=''
$ echo ${image##*/}

$ image='var3-image:asfd'
$ echo ${image##*/}
var3-image:asfd
$ image='var3-image#asfd**'
$ echo ${image##*/}
var3-image#asfd**
```

Comment: That's not a brace expansion; it's a parameter expansion. (Brace expansion refers to the expansion of something like `foo{1,2,3}` to `foo1 foo2 foo3`.)

Answer (score 0):

This removes leading `/` characters from the string.

```
$ image='/vra3-image`
$ echo ${image##*/}
vra3-image
```

From this link: ( http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html )

> Substring Removal
>
> ${string#substring} Deletes shortest match of $substring from front of
>   $string.
>
> ${string##substring} Deletes longest match of $substring from front of
>   $string.

Comment: No, it removes any prefix up through the last slash - in a common use case, any leading directory names.